Multiple figures, same caption and grouped figure numbers
I use the minipage environment and the caption package in order to obtain side by side figures in the same line, as shown in the MWE below:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{custom}
{%
    \textbf{#1#2}#3
}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{custom}{ -- }
\captionsetup
{
    format=custom,%
    labelsep=custom,%
    font={small,singlespacing},%
    skip=0pt,%
    justification=justified,%
    singlelinecheck=false
}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.8pt}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{79mm}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=79mm, height=59.25mm]{example-image-A}}
\captionof{figure}{This is A}
\end{minipage}
\hskip 0.5mm
\begin{minipage}{79mm}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=79mm, height=59.25mm]{example-image-B}}
\captionof{figure}{This is B}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}


However, I would like to group the figure numbers into a single caption, as shown below:

How can this be done?

I don't think there's a need to load the caption package for this job. Instead, I would employ the machinery of the cleveref package -- specifically, the \Cref macro.
Note that the individual graphs are associated with the labels Fig:A and Fig:B and can still be cross-referenced individually.
On the sizing of the graphs: I take it that \textwidth equals 2*79mm+1mm=159mm. I think it's easier in the longer run to use relative lengths instead of fixed numerical lengths to size the graphs. See the code below for a practical example.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\includegraphics' macro
\usepackage{cleveref} % for '\Cref' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
%\setlength{\fboxrule}{.8pt}

\begin{minipage}{0.495\linewidth}
%\fbox{
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-a}%}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{Fig:A}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.495\linewidth}
%\fbox{
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.75\linewidth]{example-image-b}%}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{Fig:B}
\end{minipage}

\smallskip\raggedright
\textbf{\Cref{Fig:A,Fig:B}} -- These are A and B, respectively.
\end{center}

\end{document}

